# where can I find this function G_STRUCT_OFFSET, I mean in which ".c", is this function implemented

Tags: linux, unix, glibc, glib

It is a macro in the glib.h, but, I am not able to get the function code.

Thanks.

Comment: you could try gcc -E and see if it expands the macro for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a macro, it's not a function and it doesn't have any separate code. The definition is contained entirely in glib.h .

You can see how it's defined, for instance, here: http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_3rd_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/gmacros_8h.html

Comment: *headdesk* I would have liked to think the GLib people knew better than to reinvent `offsetof`.

Comment: Look at the original source of the file: http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gmacros.h The point of having the macro is to be able to use `offsetof` portably on platforms that don't have it. GLib does this with a lot of other features.

Comment: There *are no* platforms that don't have `offsetof` (anymore).  It is part of C90.